# Triboelectric Nanogenerators Full bridge rectifier design

Tags: power, inductor, rectifier, bridge

I am working on energy harvesting from Triboelectric Nanogenerators abr. TENG (mechanical to electrical high impedance converters) and wanted to validate my understanding of the following circuit and generally full bridge rectifier design. Basically, I read the following paper : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/286653300_A_universal_self-charging_system_driven_by_random_biomechanical_energy_for_sustainable_operation_of_mobile_electronics which suggests the following topology for efficient energy harvesting :

[image: Triboelectric Nanogenerator power management]

I replicated the circuit and designed the full wave bridge rectifier in respect to the forward voltage of the diodes (smallest possible to have lowest voltage drop after the bridge), max reverse voltage (higher than abs of negative peak voltage) and finally with highest forward current. Knowing what my TENG power source looks like with no load, I managed to figure out the dimensioning with above considerations. I am still debugging the circuit and use a wavegenerator to generate a sine wave (5V 5hz) but have observed (with only the bridge on the full circuit) that only half of the sine shows at the output. I understood that this diode arrangement is a full wave bridge rectifier and I should see the entire wave rectified. Is that correct ? Shall I assume an error in my circuit (I used a single phase bridge rectifier : CDBHD1100L-G) ?

I can still have a closer look at this bridge issue I noticed but my real question relates to the coupled inductor and power transfer. My questions are as follows :

1- Is it normal to connect the two ends of the coupled inductors as a shared potential as seen in the schematic ? My understanding is that coupled inductors allow for electrical decoupling through the magnetic field based energy transfer and as such shouldn't be tied on one end....

2 - The paper describes thoroughly how energy transfer happens and they explain how J1 and J2 switches are critical to close/open the circuit at optimal moments to ensure efficient energy flow. In my initial testing I closed both J1 and J2 permanently and used a 25V 100 uF as Ctemp and again as Energy Storage on the other side and after testing measured almost 0V at output (with no load just oscilloscope impedance). The coupled inductor I used was a 150 uH 1A 400 mOhms one (744870151 from Wurth). My understanding is that power transfer through inductor only happens through AC , the fact I am using a large cap prior to L1 and closed J1 means I am almost supplying DC to L1 and as such do not observe anything on the other side. Switching J1 properly should allow this power transfer to happen. Are these statements correct ? Also, the inductance value relates to how much energy can be stored in an inductor. In this system, aside from the general impedance matching from start to finish is there a consideration I should observe ? I arbitrarely chose a high inductance value assuming it would allow me higher power throughput...

3- Is the following statement correct : the dimensioning of Ctemp and the coupled inductors is also influencing the general impedance matching of such a power management circuit. Since the load is not defined in my study, my approach was to rather vary the load to find perfect impedance matching at this stage rather than optimizing the input impedance of this circuit.

Thanks a lot for helping me understand the circuit and the fundamental principles better. I should still debug the circuit properly and play around (also should simulate as well) but wanted to clarify some fundamental understanding I have.